# Убрать пустые ячейки из таблицы

Tags: jquery, xhtml, html, javascript

День добрый! У меня есть таблица:

```
<table class="comparetable">
      <tbody>
         <tr>
         <td class="lable" style="width:25%;"><div class="dbg">Гарантия</div></td>
         <td class="info" style="width:25%;">
             <div class="dbg">
                 12 месяцев  
             </div>
         </td>
         <td class="info" style="width:25%;">
             <div class="dbg">
                 36 месяцев  
             </div>
         </td>
         <td class="info" style="width:25%;">
             <div class="dbg">
                 24 месяца  
             </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="lable" style="width:25%;"><div class="dbg">Мощность</div></td>
            <td class="info" style="width:25%;">
                <div class="dbg">
                    &nbsp;  
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="info" style="width:25%;">
                  <div class="dbg">
                     100 Вт  
                  </div>
              </td>
            <td class="info" style="width:25%;">
                  <div class="dbg">
                     1500 Вт  
                  </div>
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td class="lable" style="width:25%;"><div class="dbg">Операционная система</div></td>
             <td class="info" style="width:25%;">
                  <div class="dbg">
                     &nbsp;  
                  </div>
              </td>
              <td class="info" style="width:25%;">
                  <div class="dbg">
                     &nbsp;  
                  </div>
              </td>
              <td class="info" style="width:25%;">
                  <div class="dbg">
                     &nbsp;  
                  </div>
              </td>
              </tr>
                      </tbody>
 </table>
```

Мне нужно удалить все строки, где все 3 (а их может быть по-разному, больше и меньше) ячейки пустые. Как это сделать с помощью jquery?

И вторая задача, скрыть строки где все ячейки одинаковые.

Comment: Я не вижу в вашей таблице ни одной пустой ячейки. Может вы в понятие "пустой" вкладываете другое значение?

Comment: Всё верно, пусто - это где:

<pre>
    <div class="dbg">
       &nbsp;  
    </div>
</pre>

Comment: а нельзя хотя-бы без &nbsp; ? а ещё лучше без этого div

Comment: Без div точно нет, а без пробела &nbsp можно, просто задам для дива мин-высоту. Вообще первая задача не актуальна уже, а вот вторую хотелось бы решить.

Comment: Тогда вам нужно дать определение того, что такое «пустая ячейка». Общепринятое определение вам не подошло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну логика то простая. Вы выбираете tr ( `$('table.your_table_class tr').each(function(){...})`)

И в этой итерации бежите по всем `td` (`$(this).find('td').each(function(){...})`), там проверяете что они одинаковые (например перед пишете `var td_value= $(this).find('td').first().html();var result=true` и сравниваете с этим `result = result && td_value==$(this).html();` И если result == true - хайдите (`$(this).hide()`).

Принципиально не написал код как это делать, хоть это было бы и проще :-)

Comment: Я примерно понял, я на стороне сервера таким образом реализовал удаление пустых строк. Осталось сделать динамично на стороне клиента скрытие одинаковых) с этим чуток сложнее, но спасибо большое за наводку!)